# Cannot properly login to a website using PHP cURL

Tags: php, curl, post, authentication, request

I've been stumped on why my PHP cURL request is not properly signing me in to a login website (for non-personal reasons I won't disclose which one).

This is my code:

```
    $user = "TestUsername";
    $pass = "TestPassword";

    $curl = curl_init();
    $curl_config = array(
        CURLOPT_URL             => "http://website_name.com/form_action_url",
        CURLOPT_POST            => true,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  => true,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS      => array('user' => urlencode($user), 
                                        'pass' => urlencode($pass)
                                        ),
        CURLOPT_HEADER          => true,
    );
    curl_setopt_array($curl, $curl_config);
    $response= curl_exec($curl);
```

Can anyone figure out what I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What error are you getting? The login is supposed to be done posting a form right? Is this running against a real website or are you testing with localhost an xamp?

Comment: What are you expecting to happen, whats not working?

Comment: Perhaps they've detected you're doing an automated login and have blocked it. Facebook'll throw up a captcha if you try hitting their services from a cloud host's IP range, or if you're sending a cURL/wget-y user agent, or any number of other things. What response **do** you get?

Comment: Are your CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS array indexes correctly named ad expected for logging in to the website?

Comment: Why are you url encoded in the user and the pass?  Since it is a post , you are passing different data if you contain special characters

Comment: You can try `guzzlehttp/guzzle` for http requests, much easier to use than raw curl; and `fabpot/goutte` when there's need to persist cookies for things like login forms. You can find both libraries in [packagist](https://packagist.org/)

Comment: Hi guys, I'm supposed to be getting a redirect to a different website (301 code) but instead it's rejecting me from the website (200 code). Sorry for not including this! Also, yes, my CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS indices are named correctly. They are the "name=" of the <input> tags in question

Comment: Please give us full response instead of http code only

Comment: Yeah, you should probably look at the contents of that 200 response. I'll bet it contains an error message or something.